# remainder of the division of $7^{1203}$ by $143$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have to find the remainder of the division of $7^{1203}$ by $143$.
I thought that I could use the Euler Theorem:
Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.We also know that $(a,n)=1$.Then $a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$
So,we set $a=7$ and $n=143$ and see that $(a,n)=1$.So,from the above theorem,we get that $7^{120} \equiv 1 \mod 143$.
$$7^{1203} \mod 143=7^{10 \cdot 120+3} \mod 143=(7^{120})^{10} \cdot 7^{3} \mod 143=7^{3} \mod 143=57$$
So the remainder of the division of $7^{1203}$ by $143$ is $57$.Is that what I have done right or have I done something wrong??

Comment: $143=11 \times 13$, find the remainder mod $11$ and $13$ first .. then I think you will get your answer :)

Comment: Could you explain it further to me?Also,is the way that I did it wrong??

Comment: What you have done is correct ... I was just pointing out another alternative :)

Comment: evinda, you have applied Euler's theorem correctly and obtained the correct  answer 57. There is no need to work with the factors of $n$ directly (indirectly they have been used to find $\varphi(n)$).

Comment: The first sentence of the last paragraph is incomplete - there is no verb or result.

Comment: I think you'll find modular exponentiation much faster than factoring, and that all these approaches are contrived and misleading.  Contrived contest questions can mislead you about the nature of more natural mathematics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything was done correctly. The following is an "improvement" that is not needed in this case.

Imagine working separately modulo $11$ and $13$. We have $7^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$ and $7^{12}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$. Note that $60$ is the lcm of $10$ and $12$. It follows that $7^{60}\equiv 1$ modulo $11$ and $13$, and hence modulo $143$.

If your exponent has been $1263$ instead of $1203$, this observation would have saved a significant amount of time.

Note that the more distinct prime divisors the modulus $n$ has, the more we tend to save by using this type of trick.

Comment: This is formally named as Carmichael Function(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html)

Comment: $$(7^{60})^{20} \equiv 1^{20} \ (mod \ 11 \cdot 13) $$ $$ 7^{1200 + 3} \equiv 7^3 (mod 143) \\ \\$$ So it still saves time. :)

Answer (score 0):

But if you'd like to verify the above solutions via binary-squaring, here's the end-to-end formula

> `1203 = 2# 100 101 100 11`

```
mawk 'BEGIN { print (((((((((( \
                                \
   (7) % 143) ^ 2 % 143) ^ 2     % 143) ^ 2 *  \         # msb -> 100
    7  % 143) ^ 2 % 143) ^ 2 * 7 % 143) ^ 2 *   \        #        101
    7  % 143) ^ 2 % 143) ^ 2     % 143) ^ 2 *    \       #        100  
                               7 % 143) ^ 2 * 7 % 143    #         11 <- lsb
}'
```

---

```
57
```